# Get an access token from Instagram API WITHOUT a browser?

Tags: http, web, backend, instagram-api

I'm working on a project where I pull in data from social media according to certain queries and analyze them. Currently I'm pulling in Instagram media data. 
The only thing I want to do is to input a query and get JSON media/likes/comments.... I read the documentation of their API. I found that I couldn't get an access token without authorizing using my own account in a browser. I know there's gotta be a user, so I assume using my own account is fine. But the problem is that I don't want to get an access token manually from a browser.

Currently I'm hardcoding the access token. It will expire and I have to update it manually every time. I bet there's a better solution. Could someone help me out? Thanks.

```
class instagramFeed():

    CLIENT_ID = "MY-APP-ID" 
    REDIRECT_URI = "MY-ORGANIZATIONS-URI"
    ACCESS_TOKEN = "I MANUALLY GENERATE THIS TOKEN"
    query = None

    def __init__(self):
        None

    def get_data(self, query):
        response = urllib2.urlopen("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q="+query+"&access_token="+self.ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get `access_token` without logging in on Instagram page, thats the whole point of oauth authentication.

You will have to manually get `access_token` and update, from my experience the Instagram `access_token` never expires, I have used it for 6 years. Only time you have to get new `access_token` is if Instagram revokes it because of suspicious activity detected. So as long as you use the API carefully without automating too much back-to back calls, you should be good with the same `access_token`.

Comment: Thanks. The access token I got before did expire, probably because I got it from client-side implicit flow. If the access token I get from server-side flow doesn't expire, then I think I'm good :)

Comment: are u in sandbox or live mode? I mostly use server-side oauth, it may make a difference, not sure